# How do I create a better quality image converting a .pdf to a .jpg with Imagick/PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I currently have a single page PDF (http://reljac.com/so_1/all.pdf) which is a basic scan of several paper receipts.  If you look at the PDF the text is clear and legible.  The original is a scan of an 8.5" x 11" sheet of paper (shouldn't matter)

I've created a very simple file to convert that PDF into a .jpg using this code:

```
<?php     
    $im = new imagick('all.pdf[0]');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_LOSSLESSJPEG); 
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo $im;
?>
```

When I run that (http://reljac.com/so_1/pdf_jpg.php) the resulting image is illegible.

I'm working off of two servers at the moment, one tells me:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 10/06/10 Q16
>   file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html

the other:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-05-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org

Both servers create a similar quality .jpg

I've changed several of the settings including:

- `$im->setImageCompressionQuality(40);`
- `$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);`
- `$im->setImageCompressionQuality(80);`
- `$im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);` (various others from http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php)

I've tried adding `$im->scaleImage(600,0);`

Nothing seems to make anything more legible. I'd like the end result to be a legible .jpg of the original PDF - it does not have to fill the screen, it just needs to be legible.  The original PDFs may be different sizes so I need to keep in mind that the source is not always 8.5" x 11".

Is there anything else I can do to enhance the quality of the resulting image or is this the best I should expect?  Do I need to process these files in some other way to get a better image?

**UPDATE**
Based on @VadimR's answer I'm now using the following:

```
$src = 'all.pdf';
$src_parts = pathinfo($src);

shell_exec('pdfimages ' . $src . ' ' . $src_parts['filename']);
shell_exec('convert ' . $src_parts['filename'] . '-000.pbm -resize 25% -sharpen -2 ' . $src_parts['filename'] . '.jpg');

$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_parts['filename'] . '.jpg');
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($myImage);
imagedestroy($myImage);

shell_exec('rm ' . $src_parts['filename'] . '-000.pbm');
```

That results in a nice, legible image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick delegates PDF rendering to Ghostscript, therefore for troubleshooting specify not only IM, but GS version, too, if necessary. Second, I think it's better to start with command line, and only after appropriate quality is achieved, put it into php code.

Command that gives quality (more or less):

```
convert -density 300 all.pdf out.jpg
```

Here we set rendering resolution 300 dpi. Note, it's not the same as

```
convert all.pdf -density 300 out.jpg
```

because here rendering goes at 72 dpi, then bad quality result is assigned (i.e. w/o resampling) with 300 dpi.

But, I think better approach can be to extract scans **as is** i.e. without transformations:

```
pdfimages all.pdf all
```

that gives all-000.pbm image -- 1-bit per sample, 3424*4400 px. I definitely can't agree, that "text is clear and legible" - some digits can only be guessed.

Then use `convert` command to resample and maybe try to improve e.g.

```
convert all-000.pbm -resize 25% -sharpen 2 out.jpg
```

Comment: Question for you...does this only work on pdf files that are image only?  If the file was created by saving a document as a pdf would this not work?

Comment: @Jason, using `pdfimages` to convert a page works if a page is exactly one image. Otherwise render PDF to image with Ghostscript or another tool, including IM's `convert` (which uses GS).

Answer (score -1):

Using **pdfimages** to extract images (yes, it can extract 100s of 1000s of images from a single PDF document) of scanned pages and saving the same as pbm or ppm files is a much better option or technique.

"Every other operation and, or repeated conversions etc. will/can definitely reduce originality and sometimes even the quality of images, if you don't know what you're doing with them, the images. For example someone suggested to use JPEG format, a loosy compression/encoding method, indeed. Whereas, the raw image formats like pbm or mono for grayscale, black & white and, or 1-bit images and ppm for 24/16/8-bit colored images."

*Operate only on the raw images and finally use Jbig2enc for conversion of pbm images to PDF files and leptocica's converttopdf utility for colored pages.*

**DON'T EVER USE RESIZE TO REDUCE THE SIZE OF OUTPUT PAGES/PDF FILES, LEARN TO USE A BETTER COMPRESSION and, or ENCODING TECHNIQUE!**